# Insertar botones y editText en un FragmentPagerAdapter Android

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo un FragmentPagerAdapter que carga en una actividad de la app que estoy desarrollando. Ahora mismo lo que le paso son los valores de el color de fondo que tendra el adapter. Aun que mi intencion es la de realizar dos Adapter donde contenga un editText y dos botones que al pulsar sobre un boton desencadene una acción.

Basicamente lo que tengo en mente es de tener dos Adapter con la misma estructura pero uno para meter cierto tipo de dato y en el otro editText otro tipo de dato.

fragment_screen_slide_page.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvIndex"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/letra"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="75sp" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/btnFragment"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/btnFragment2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="50sp"
    android:layout_height="150sp"
    android:id="@+id/eTxtFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ScreenSlidePageFragment.java :

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

/**
 * Key to insert the background color into the mapping of a Bundle.
 */
private static final String BACKGROUND_COLOR = "color";

/**
 * Key to insert the index page into the mapping of a Bundle.
 */
private static final String INDEX = "index";

private int color;
private int index;

/**
 * Instances a new fragment with a background color and an index page.
 *
 * @param color background color
 * @param index index page
 * @return a new page
 */
public static ScreenSlidePageFragment newInstance(int color, int index) {

    // Instantiate a new fragment
    ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();

    // Save the parameters
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(BACKGROUND_COLOR, color);
    bundle.putInt(INDEX, index);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragment.setRetainInstance(true);

    return fragment;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Load parameters when the initial creation of the fragment is done
    this.color = (getArguments() != null) ? getArguments().getInt(
            BACKGROUND_COLOR) : Color.GRAY;
    this.index = (getArguments() != null) ? getArguments().getInt(INDEX)
            : -1;

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

    // Muestra la pagina en la que se encuentra el indice
    TextView tvIndex = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvIndex);
    tvIndex.setText(String.valueOf(this.index));

    // Cambia el color de fondo
    rootView.setBackgroundColor(this.color);

    // Inicializa el boton del fragment
    ToggleButton btnFragment = (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnFragment);
    ToggleButton btnFragment2 = (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnFragment2);

    EditText eTxtFragment = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.eTxtFragment);

    return rootView;

}
}
```

MyFragmentPagerAdapter.java

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

// List of fragments which are going to set in the view pager widget
List<Fragment> fragments;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param fm interface for interacting with Fragment objects inside of an
 *           Activity
 */
public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
}

/**
 * Add a new fragment in the list.
 *
 * @param fragment a new fragment
 */
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragments.add(fragment);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    return this.fragments.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Página " + (position + 1);
}
}
```

Instancio y sobrecargo el fragment de esta manera en la actividad que la uso:

```
        // Instantiate a ViewPager
    this.pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    // Create an adapter with the fragments we show on the ViewPager
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.background2), 0));
    adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.background2), 1));
    this.pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Y este es la idea del planteamiento:
[image: IDEA]

Cualquier idea es de ayuda, gracias !!!

Comment: Que no consigues exactamente, ¿agregar los botones y edittext, o los eventos click? Para agregar un elemento, en el adapter sobreescribe el metodo **getItem()** e inflas un fragment segun la posicion del pager 
`@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0: 
                return PrimerFragment.newInstance(0, "fragment # 1");
            case 1: 
                return SegundoFragment.newInstance(1, "fragment# 2");
            default:
             return null;
            }
        }`

Comment: bfff no lo entiendo... trato de sustituir el valor (0 y 1) por un cajetin de EditText para poder insertar numeros y dos ToogleButton para que al introducir datos y pulse a un boton desencadene una activity.

Comment: lo que tienes que crear una clase que extienda de un Fragment e inflarlas ahi, si saco un rato hago un codigo de ejemplo. No obstante, no me quedo claro del todo. En la imagen que muestras colocas 2 botones y 1 edittext, que supongo quieres sea deslizable de un lado a otro. Basicamente es crear un adapter, con un fragment, en el fragment colocas los botones, edittext... y asignas ese fragment con su adapter al pager, y segun la posicion del pager pones un contenido u otro

Comment: tratare de realizarlo aunque no estoy muy seguro de como hacerlo. Mi idea es la de tener dos deslizables, donde tenga un edittext y dos button en una vista y el mismo contenido en otro. Si puedes adjuntarme algo parecido a lo que te comento me echaras mas que un cable @Israel

Comment: acabo de actualizar la pregunta y he insertado todo el código y el ciclo que tiene al la hora de cargar las clases etc. El código esta en orden de ejecución

Comment: Te facilito un tutorial que enseña a trabajar con los pager https://amatellanes.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/android-ejemplo-de-viewpager-en-android-parte-1/ Tras leerlo intenta adaptarlo a tu codigo, por mi parte cuando saque tiempo formulo una respuesta con el codigo de ejemplo